# I want to display a list in Android

Tags: android, list, task

I want to create a list of tasks in Android. 
So, i have created a Class named Task, this class have this some properties (Name, Date, description). 
And I have created a TaskList too, this list extends TreeSet.

I want to show this list in Android, and I don't know how. 
In the future I want that when the user click on the task, he can change the properties.

What is correct to do? Create a Fragment for Task? Use ListAdapter for the List of Tasks? What is the best way? Please give me the right way to implement this and I will search to code it

I wish that looks like:

................

Task 1

Go to college

Date: 07/04/2016

................

Task 2

Buy a water

Date: 08/04/2016

...............

Task 3

Read a book

Date: 09/04/2016

...............

Thanks!

Comment: Use recyclerview or listview example to get an idea. All you need to do is write an adapter.

Comment: read about creating listview with custom base adapter. this is what you want.

Comment: `RecyclerView` is best option

Comment: see this link its help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Your question title is inappropriate. You should give hint of your problem instead of what you want to do in title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Recyclerview. It's better than ListView and provides default animations while adding and removing items. A complete example can be found [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comments the best way to do this is with a RecyclerView or a ListView.

Here is a good guide to getting a RecyclerView set up:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/